# Can the Fenchel conjugate be characterized through the Fenchel-Young inequality?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, duality-theorems

It is known (see for example [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1427975/how-equality-in-fenchel-young-inequality-characterizes-subdifferential)), that the Fenchel conjugate of a smooth function $f: \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ verifies the identity
$$
f(x) + f^\star(\nabla f(x)) = \langle x, \nabla f(x)\rangle~.
$$

Is it true that this identity characterizes the Fenchel conjugate? That is, is $f^\star$ the only function that verifies the above identity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In view of the question you linked in your question above (and answers thereof), we know that if $f$ is convex l.s.c, then
$f(x) + f^*(u) = \langle x,u\rangle \iff u \in \partial f(x)$, where $\partial f(x) \subseteq X^*$ is the subdifferential of $f$ at $x$ defined by

$$
\partial f(x) := \{x^* \in X^* \mid f(x') \ge f(x) + \langle x^*, x'-x\rangle\;\forall x' \in X\}
$$

Here $X^*$ is the *topological dual* of the real (or complex!) Banach space $X$, the space of all linear functionals $X \mapsto \mathbb R$. 
The mapping $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle : X^* \times X \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is the *duality bracket*. We consider Banach spaces and not just Hilbert spaces because we want to be as general as reasonable (think about function spaces, spaces of probability distributions, etc.).
We'll assume $X$ is *reflexive*, which means $X^{**} = X$. A crash course on convex analysis in Banach spaces can be found [here](https://dohmatob.github.io/research/2019/10/31/duality.html).

To answer the first part of your question in the affirmative, it then suffices to prove that

> **Lemma.** *If $f$ is convex and differentiable at $x$, then $\partial f(x) = \{\nabla f(x)\}$, i.e $\nabla f(x)$ is the unique subgradient of $f$ at $x$.*

*Proof.* See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1989140/168758. $\quad\quad\Box$

This proves that

> The choice $g=f^*$ solves the functional equation
>   $$
> \begin{split}
> &f(x) + g^\star(\nabla f(x)) = \langle x, \nabla f(x)\rangle\;\forall x \in \text{intdom}\;f,\\
> &g:\text{intdom}\;f^* \rightarrow X,
> \end{split}
> \tag{FY}
> $$

where $\text{intdom}\;f$ is the interior of $\text{dom}\;f := \{x \in X \mid f(x) < +\infty\}$.

## On the uniqueness of $f^*$ as a solution of (FY)

Suppose that $f$ is a **Legendre function**, meaning that

- $f$ is convex l.s.c and continuously differentiable on $\text{intdom}\; f$, and
- the gradient-mapping $\nabla f: \text{intdom}\;f \rightarrow X^*$ is one-to-one (a sufficient condition is that this $f$ is essentially strictly convex; see **Fact 2.4** and **Corollary 2.6** of https://people.ok.ubc.ca/bauschke/Research/07.pdf).

Then $f^*$ is also a Legendre function and one has the following conjugate-inversion formulae (see Rockafellar's *Convex Analysis*, **Theorem 26.5** for proof!)

> $\nabla f^*\nabla f=\text{ the identity operator on }\text{int}\text{dom}\;f$,
>   $\nabla f\nabla f^* = \text{ the identity operator on }\text{int}\text{dom}\;f^*$.

Now, back to our problem. Suppose $g:\text{int}\;\text{dom}\;f^* \rightarrow X$ is another function which satisfies (FY), and let $u  \in \text{int}\;\text{dom}\;f^*$. Then by the above conjugate-inversion formula, we have $u=\nabla f(x_u)$ where $x_u = \nabla f^*(u) \in \text{intdom}\;f$. Thus

$$
g(u) = g(\nabla f (x_u)) = \langle x_u ,\nabla f(x_u)\rangle - f(x_u) = f^*(\nabla f(x_u)) = f^*(u),
$$

where the 2nd and 3rd equalities are due to the fact that $g$ and $f^*$ solve (FY).

The above equation shows that $g=f^*$ on $\text{intdom}f^*$, thus proving the unicity of $f^*$ as solution to the functional equation (FY). $\quad\quad\Box$

## We have the hammer, where are the nails ?

Note that a by-product of our above analysis is that

> *The conjugate $f^*$ can be explicity computed like so*
>   $$
> f^*(u) = \langle (\nabla f)^{-1}(u),u\rangle - f((\nabla f)^{-1}(u)),
> \;\forall u \in \text{intdom} f^*.
> \tag{1}
> $$

As an example, let's prove the popular statement

> *"Log-sum-exp" is the convex conjugate of "relative entropy"*.

More precisely, let $X$ be the real Banach space of Radon measures on a topological space $\Omega$ (e.g a finite set), so that $X^*$ is the space of continuous functions on $\Omega$ equipped with the sup-norm, and the duality bracket is given for every $(v,\nu) \in X^* \times X$ by $\langle \nu, v\rangle = \mathbb E_\nu[v] := \int_\Omega vd\nu$. Now, fix a base measure $\mu$ on $\Omega$, and consider the so-called relative entropy functional (relative to the base measure $\mu$)

$$
\begin{split}
H(\cdot\|\mu): X &\rightarrow (-\infty,+\infty],\\
\nu &\mapsto H(\nu \| \mu) := \begin{cases}\mathbb E_{\nu}\left[\log\left(\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}\right)\right] = \int_{\Omega}\log\left(\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}\right)d\nu,&\mbox{ if }\nu \ll \mu,\\+\infty,&\mbox{ else.}\end{cases}
\end{split}
$$
Here, $\dfrac{d\nu}{d\mu}$ is the *Radon-Nikodym derivative* of $\nu$ w.r.t $\mu$.
One can easily check that this is a Legendre function. Now, let $\nu$ be a probability distribution on $\Omega$ with $\nu \ll \mu$, and let $u:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a continuous function. The following computations are trivial

- $\nabla f(\nu) = \log\left(\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}\right) + 1$ (pointwise logarithm), and so $\nabla f(\nu) = u$ iff $d\nu = (e^{u}/Z)d\mu$, where $Z_u = \mathbb E_\mu[e^u]$.
- Thus $(\nabla H(\cdot\|\mu))^{-1}(u) \ll \mu$ with Radon-Nikodym derivative equal to $e^u/Z_u$.

Plugging into formula (1) with $f=H(\cdot\|\mu)$, we get

$$
\begin{split}
H(\cdot\|\mu)^*(u) &= \langle (\nabla H(\cdot\|\mu))^{-1}(u),u\rangle - f((\nabla H(\cdot\|\mu))^{-1}(u))\\
&= \int_\Omega (ue^u/Z_u) d\mu - \int_\Omega \left(e^u/Z_u\right)\log\left(e^u/Z_u\right)d\mu\\
&= \mathbb E_{\mu}[ue^u/Z_u] - \mathbb E_{\mu}[ue^u/Z_u] + \log(Z_u)
= \log(Z_u) = \log(\mathbb E_\mu[e^u]).
\end{split}
$$

*How cool is that ?*

Comment: It's pretty cool!